# Thread.sleep() freezes JFrame/GUI containing GraphStream graph

Tags: java, algorithm, swing, concurrency, graphstream

My `JFrame` containing an embedded single graph ([Graphstream](http://graphstream-project.org/)) freezes when I try to update it in a loop that calls Thread,sleep(). I have tried using the same update on a standalone-graph (displayed on it's own) and it works as expected.

I have a single graph embedded in JFrame as follows (AppGraph.java):

```
public static ViewPanel init(){

    graph.addAttribute("ui.stylesheet", styleSheet);
    graph.setAutoCreate(true);
    graph.setStrict(false);
    graph.addAttribute("ui.quality");
    graph.addAttribute("ui.antialias");

    initGraph();

    initNodes(graph);

    return attachViewPanel();

}

private static ViewPanel attachViewPanel() {
    Viewer viewer = new Viewer(graph, Viewer.ThreadingModel.GRAPH_IN_ANOTHER_THREAD);
    viewer.enableAutoLayout();
    return viewer.addDefaultView(false);
}

private static void initGraph(){
    FileSource fs = new FileSourceDOT();
    String graph_filename = "graph.gv";
    String absolute_path = System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator + graph_filename;
    fs.addSink(graph);
    try {
        fs.readAll(absolute_path);
    } catch (IOException | NullPointerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        fs.removeSink(graph);
    }
}
```

Then this is called in the JFrame class as below:

```
   /*AppWindow.java
    * Set up graph
    */
    GridBagConstraints graphConstraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    graphConstraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    graphConstraints.gridx = 0;
    graphConstraints.gridy = 1;
    graphConstraints.weightx = 0.5;
    graphConstraints.weighty = 0.5;
    graphConstraints.gridwidth = 4;
    graphConstraints.gridheight = GridBagConstraints.RELATIVE;
    add(AppGraph.init(), graphConstraints);`
```

On the `JFrame` are buttons for different search algorithms like BFS. During the execution of these algorithms, edges traversed are colored at fixed time intervals to create a sort of animation effect as shown below:

```
   //BFSAlgorithm.java 
   private void callBFS(Node startNode, Node goalNode) {
            startNode.setAttribute("parent", "null");
            startNode.setAttribute("level", 0);
            startNode.setAttribute("visited?");
            LinkedList<Node> queueFrontier = new LinkedList<>();
            int level = 1;
            queueFrontier.addLast(startNode);
            while (!queueFrontier.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Level: " + (level - 1));
                LinkedList<Node> next = new LinkedList<>();
                for (Node node : queueFrontier) {
                    if (node == goalNode) {
                        System.out.println(node.getId() + ": Found Found Found!!!");
                        if (node != startNode) {
                            colorEdge(node);
                        }
                        return;
                    }
                    System.out.print(node.getId() + " visited \t");
                    if (node != startNode) {
                        colorEdge(node);
                    }
                    for (Edge edge : node.getEdgeSet()) {
                        Node opposite = edge.getOpposite(node);
                        if (!opposite.hasAttribute("visited?")) {
                            System.out.print(opposite.getId() + " enqueued \t");
                            opposite.setAttribute("level", level);
                            opposite.setAttribute("parent", node);
                            opposite.setAttribute("visited?");
                            next.addLast(opposite);
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.print("\n");
                }
                level++;
                queueFrontier = next;
                sleep();
        }
    }

    private void colorEdge(Node node) {
        Edge visitedEdge = node.getEdgeBetween(node.getAttribute("parent", Node.class));
        visitedEdge.setAttribute("ui.color", 0.5);
        sleep();
    }

    private void sleep() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(AppWindow.speed);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

This `BFSAlgorithm` implements `DynamicAlgorithm` and extends `SinkAdapter`. I have extended the `SinkAdapter` to enable it to interact with the View as the algorithm runs. When I call the `BFSAlgorithm`, while the algorithm runs and the various `println` statements are delayed by `sleep()`, the GUI freezes and is unresponsive until after execution before all the visited edges are then colored. I tried implementing `ViewerListener` in my `AppGraph.java` as is documented on the [graphstream documentation](http://graphstream-project.org/doc/Tutorials/Graph-Visualisation/) but it only resulted in an infinite loop that crashed the application:

```
/*...init() method from AppGraph.java*/
ProxyPipe fromViewer = viewer.newThreadProxyOnGraphicGraph();
        fromViewer.addSink(graph);
        fromViewer.pump();

while(loop) {
            fromViewer.pump(); //

}
```

Comment: Have a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Well I don't have enought time to answer but you should use a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead

Comment: try re-validating the JPanel that your graph is on

Comment: @rert588 Do you mean call repaint() method in the BFSAlgorithm?

Comment: @MadProgrammer and Frakcool Thanks! I used a [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) after reading up on the SwingWorker and Consurrency. I dont think you can mark comments as answers though

Comment: @Korogba no, but you can answer your own question and mark it as accepted answer :) (Just be sure to place your code too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Frakool and @MadProgrammer suggested in the comments, if anyone is having similar issues, using `SwingWorker` and [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) will provide the desired results. According to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html):

> In general, we recommend using Swing timers rather than general-purpose timers for GUI-related tasks because Swing timers all share the same, pre-existing timer thread and the GUI-related task automatically executes on the event-dispatch thread. However, you might use a general-purpose timer if you don't plan on touching the GUI from the timer, or need to perform lengthy processing.

Here's how I used it to stop the gui freezing. I created a private inner `SwingWorker` class that uses a `Swing Timer` as below:

```
private class BFSTask extends SwingWorker<LinkedList<Node>, Node>{
    private ArrayList<Node> visitedList;
    private int visitedIndex = 0;
    private boolean traversalDone = false;
    private Timer traversal = new Timer(AppWindow.speed, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
            Node lastVisited = visitedList.get(visitedIndex);
            Edge visitedEdge = lastVisited.getEdgeBetween(lastVisited.getAttribute("parent", Node.class));
            visitedEdge.setAttribute("ui.color", 0.5);
            visitedIndex++;
            if(visitedIndex >= visitedList.size()){
                traversal.stop();
                traversalDone = true;
                if(BFSAlgorithm.this.getPathToGoal() != null){
                    startTimer();
                }
            }
        }
    });

     @Override
    protected LinkedList<Node> doInBackground() throws Exception {
        Node found = publishNodeBreadthFirst(getStartNode(), getGoalNode());
        if (found != null) {
            return getPathToGoal(found);
        } else{
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Node> list) {
        visitedList = (ArrayList<Node>) list;
        traversal.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            BFSAlgorithm.this.pathToGoal = get();
            if(traversalDone && BFSAlgorithm.this.getPathToGoal() != null){
                startTimer();
            }
            if(BFSAlgorithm.this.getPathToGoal() == null){
                throw new NullPointerException("Goal Not Found.");
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(getAppWindow(), "Goal Node Not Found!", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            getAppWindow().disableExceptClear();
            getAppWindow().changeStatus("Goal node not found");

        }
    }

    private LinkedList<Node> getPathToGoal(Node found) {
        LinkedList<Node> path = new LinkedList<>();
        Node parent = found.getAttribute("parent");
        path.addLast(found);
        while (parent != getStartNode()){
            path.addLast(parent);
            parent = parent.getAttribute("parent");
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem as you had. When i call my class that contains the graph, it doesnt render the nodes. So i used a SwingWorker to put the graph on another thread. Ok, it rendered, but now the viewlistener doesnt work, i do not have answer from the user interaction (clicking on nodes). You can see here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36899115/graphstream-view-not-loading/36900197